# How to get nearest theater listing depending upon zipcode?

Tags: java, api

I need to find list of near by theaters depending upon user zipcode input, I have an api which gives this information if we pass zipcode but am not sure as to how to use this api, this is my first time trying to get data from api and am not familiar with `atom`, `pox` and `ast` acronyms.

API that gives theater information is located at http://gateway.moviefone.com/, any guidance suggestion would be highly appreciate to get started with using this api and understanding about how to work with api's.

Comment: http://gateway.moviefone.com/movies/rss/closesttheaters.xml?zip=YOURZIPCODE, then parse the contents? User enters zip you fill in url and then parse contents. Each movie theater is encompassed by item tags so you can parse it like an xml document, not to familiar with Java however....

Comment: @Andrew: What is `ast` or `pox` ?

Comment: They appear to be slightly different data structures similar to XML. 
AST -> http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/JsonMLASTFormat
POX = "Plain ol XML"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several steps involved, here's some pseudocode to help you get started:

```
String zip = "...";
String url = "http://gateway.moviefone.com/movies/pox/closesttheaters.xml?zip=" + zip;

// read and parse the xml
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(url);

//get elements you need
NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("closestTheatersUrl");
String urlForTheater = list.item(0).getNodeValue();
```